# Why do I get 0 when running my "mult(num)" function?

Tags: python, function

I am a noob in Python and I got stuck with the following code. I can't figure out why my function 'mult(num') can't calculate sum 'su' even though inside the function when I run print(su, end="   ") it gives all numbers I expect?

```
def mult(num):
    su = 0
    for i in range(num):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
            su += i
            return su
            # print(su, end="   ")  when running this line I see >>>> 0   3   8   14   23   33   45   60


print(mult(18))
```

output

```
>>>  0
```

Why do I get 0?

Comment: The indentation of the `return su` statement is incorrect. You want it outside the loop.

Comment: Think about what the code does the first time through the loop, when i=0.

Comment: What tutorial told you that the function keeps going after a `return`? That's a bad tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `return su` you exit the function. You quit on the first iteration of the loop, so the answer is `0`.

Fixed code:

```py
def mult(num):
    su = 0
    for i in range(num):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
            su += i
            #return su
    
    return su


print(mult(18))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is a problem in the indentation of `return su`.
The code should be corrected as follows.

```
def mult(num):
    su = 0
    for i in range(num):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
            su += i

    return su

print(mult(18))
```

Note that the `return su` is only executed one time even it is inside a loop. That is why your code gets the output as 0.